# Include all possible values of sub-categories under each category

Tags: sql-server, query

How can it be achieved in MS SQL 2016, when I need to always see every `state` under all existing `categories` even if there are no records, which satisfy the `state` formula?

Under `a` and `b` below I always want to see all three of `later`, `earlier`, and `same` with `null` counts whenever there is no corresponding record.

I guess it should be achievable with some sort of `cross join`?..

```
declare @t table (tid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    ,tcat char(1)
    ,tdat1 date
    ,tdat2 date
)

insert into @t select * from (values
     ('a', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')
    ,('a', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01')
)as t(tcat, tdat1, tdat2)

select
    tcat as category
    ,case
        when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
        when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
        when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
    end         as state
    ,count(1)   as howmany
from @t
group by
    tcat
    ,case
        when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
        when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
        when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
    end
```

Comment: It's not absolutely clear what your intended result is. Are you looking for your final result to have `later`, `earlier`, and `same` columns? Or do you want three rows for each category, correspond to those three values. I recommend you [edit] in an example of the expected output, as that may make your question clearer.

Comment: are A and B fixed categories or can you change them?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, here is *one* way to achieve your goal

```
--demo setup
declare @t table (tid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    ,tcat char(1)
    ,tdat1 date
    ,tdat2 date
)

insert into @t select * from (values
     ('a', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')
    ,('a', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01')
)as t(tcat, tdat1, tdat2)

--the solution
;with BaseData as
(
select
    tcat as category
    ,case
        when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
        when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
        when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
    end         as state
    ,count(1)   as howmany
from @t
group by
    tcat
    ,case
        when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
        when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
        when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
    end
) 
select * from BaseData
union 
select tcat,'later' as state, 0 as howmany from @t t
where not exists(select * from basedata where category = t.tcat and state = 'later')
union 
select tcat,'earlier' as state, 0 as howmany from @t t
where not exists(select * from basedata where category = t.tcat and state = 'earlier')
union 
select tcat,'same' as state, 0 as howmany from @t t
where not exists(select * from basedata where category = t.tcat and state = 'same')
```

---

```
| category | state   | howmany |
|----------|---------|---------|
| a        | earlier | 1       |
| a        | later   | 1       |
| a        | same    | 0       |
| b        | earlier | 0       |
| b        | later   | 1       |
| b        | same    | 1       |
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple approach that uses `CROSS JOIN` to project all possible combinations of category and state, then `OUTER JOIN` to the data.

```
declare @t table (tid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    ,tcat char(1)
    ,tdat1 date
    ,tdat2 date
);

insert into @t select * from (values
     ('a', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')
    ,('a', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01')
)as t(tcat, tdat1, tdat2);

WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        tcat AS category,
        CASE
            WHEN tdat1 > tdat2 THEN 'later'
            WHEN tdat1 < tdat2 THEN 'earlier'
            WHEN tdat1 = tdat2 THEN 'same'
        END AS STATE,
        COUNT(1) AS howmany
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY
        tcat,
        CASE
            WHEN tdat1 > tdat2 THEN 'later'
            WHEN tdat1 < tdat2 THEN 'earlier'
            WHEN tdat1 = tdat2 THEN 'same'
        END
)
SELECT
    tcat.category,
    p.state,
    ISNULL(t.howmany, 0) AS howmany
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tcat AS category FROM @t) tcat
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('earlier'), ('same'), ('later')) p(state)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t
        ON tcat.category = t.category
        AND p.state = t.state
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method (similar to @db2's answer):

```
with
  grp as
  ( select
        tcat,
        sign(datediff(day, tdat2, tdat1)) as sgn,
        count(1)   as howmany
    from @t
    group by
        tcat,
        sign(datediff(day, tdat2, tdat1))
  )
select 
    cat.tcat as category,
    st.state,
    coalesce(grp.howmany, 0) as howmany
from
    ( values
        (-1, 'earlier'),
        ( 0, 'same'),
        (+1, 'later')
    ) as st (sgn, state)
    cross join
    ( select distinct tcat
      from @t
    ) as cat (tcat)
    left join grp 
      on  grp.sgn = st.sgn
      and grp.tcat = cat.tcat ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=501f8baf4b9f2772da38d0c36574a236)**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to display your results, you can use PIVOT or UNPIVOT to present "same, earlier, later" as columns or rows:

More info: [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Columns:

```
declare @t table (tid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    ,tcat char(1)
    ,tdat1 date
    ,tdat2 date
)

insert into @t select * from (values
     ('a', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')
    ,('a', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01')
)as t(tcat, tdat1, tdat2)

SELECT category,
    COALESCE(pvt.later, 0) AS later,
    COALESCE(pvt.earlier, 0) AS earlier,
    COALESCE(pvt.same, 0) AS same
FROM
(
    select
        tcat as category
        ,case
            when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
            when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
            when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
        end         as state
        ,count(1)   as howmany
    from @t
    group by
        tcat
        ,case
            when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
            when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
            when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
        end
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(howmany) FOR [state] IN ([later], [earlier], [same])
) pvt
```

Output:

```
category    later   earlier same
--------------------------------
a           1       1       0
b           1       0       1
```

Rows:

```
declare @t table (tid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    ,tcat char(1)
    ,tdat1 date
    ,tdat2 date
)

insert into @t select * from (values
     ('a', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')
    ,('a', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01')
    ,('b', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01')
)as t(tcat, tdat1, tdat2)

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT category,
        COALESCE(pvt.later, 0) AS later,
        COALESCE(pvt.earlier, 0) AS earlier,
        COALESCE(pvt.same, 0) AS same
    FROM
    (
        select
            tcat as category
            ,case
                when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
                when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
                when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
            end         as state
            ,count(1)   as howmany
        from @t
        group by
            tcat
            ,case
                when tdat1 > tdat2 then 'later'
                when tdat1 < tdat2 then 'earlier'
                when tdat1 = tdat2 then 'same'
            end
    ) src
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(howmany) FOR [state] IN ([later], [earlier], [same])
    ) pvt
)src
UNPIVOT
(
    Howmany for State IN ([later], [earlier], [same])
) upv
```

Output:

```
category    Howmany State
------------------------
a           1       later
a           1       earlier
a           0       same
b           1       later
b           0       earlier
b           1       same
```